# PostgreSQL: can this query could be shorter?

Tags: postgresql

**table 'product'**

| id | product_name | product_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | foo | this is foo desc |
| 2. | bar | bar desc |
| 3 | goo. | goo desc. |

**Junction table 'ingredient_product'**

| id | product_id | ingredient_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |

**table 'ingredient'**

| id | ingredient_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | chicken |
| 3 | beef |
| 4 | chicken fat |
| 5 | oat |
| 6 | pea fibre |

```
const {keyword} = req.query

const response = await pool.query(
      'SELECT product.name AS product_name FROM product 
       JOIN ingredient_product ON ingredient_product.product_id = product.id 
       JOIN ingredient ON ingredient_product.ingredient_id = ingredient.id 
       WHERE ingredient.name ILIKE $1',
       [`%${keyword}%`]
    );
```

Hi, I am very new to sql, and my queries always seem to be very long.

So I've been wondering if this query(above) can be shortened? or is there any better way to write?

Thank you!

Comment: Just remember: shorter is not always means more efficient.

Comment: @Abelisto will do! Thank you!

Comment: @Abelisto On the record (file) level, a full sequential scan will happen on the ingredient table, that is unavoidable because ILIKE is generally not indexable. Then, depending on the results/heuristics, this will be eaten by other index scans. All the queries mentioned on this page will be optimized to this on the procedural level, there is no really way to make it better optimized. There is a way to make it simpler.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica "a full sequential scan will happen on the ingredient table, that is unavoidable" - wrong. With `exists` scan will stop on the first found tuple. Tha's why the filtering data using `exists` usually **faster** then the filtering by joins.

Comment: @Abelisto Wrong - to get all the ingredient names matching the pattern, something needs to scan the whole table. There is no way to avoid this.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8d9322332d00af46b431267237234c34 The `exists` solution is more then 3 times faster then the join one. Hope the discussion finished on this point.

Comment: @Abelisto Yes, it is faster - except that 1) the table structure in completely different as in the question 2) and also the distribution of the elements are completely different 3) and it still does a seq scan for the ILIKE.

Comment: @Abelisto [pg_trm](https://niallburkley.com/blog/index-columns-for-like-in-postgres/) extension can be used to index LIKE conditions.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

There is no conceptionally simpler way to do this. You can do a little syntactical simplification - instead of using `JOIN`s, you can `SELECT` from multiple tables and then filter them with `WHERE`-conditions:

```
SELECT product.name AS product_name
FROM product, ingredient_product, ingredient
WHERE
  ingredient.name ILIKE $1
  AND
  ingredient_product.product_id = product.id
  AND
  ingredient_product.ingredient_id = ingredient.id
```

The shortest query (in char length) what I can imagine is this:

```
SELECT p.name AS product_name FROM product p, ingredient_product b, ingredient i WHERE i.name ILIKE $1 AND b.product_id = product.id AND b.ingredient_id = ingredient.id
```

On the record level, all of these will do the same.

Comment: Please do not advocate the ancient and outdated implicit joins in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mean it's not good to use JOINS?

Comment: @DonKim: using joins is absolutely fine, but they should be done using an explicit JOIN operator, not the ancient implicit join conditions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please do not enforce your induvidual taste to others, particularly if their solution is completely standard and safe.

Comment: It's not my individual taste. Many people think the way I do, see e.g. here https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event9/T-SQL_Bad_Habits_to_Kick

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry my English is not very good but I like to understand it correctly. so, use JOIN without WHERE clause is a better way to write.  Did I get it right?

Comment: @DonKim It can be done on both ways. "a_horse_with_no_name" came here and simply declared that doing this is bad. He has no reason to say that, just declared it. It is up to you, what you do. My solution switched from the JOIN-form to the mult-table selection to make your query simpler, that is all.

Comment: @DonKim: your JOIN conditions are absolutely fine. Many people think they are much better than the ancient and outdated implicit join conditions in the WHERE clause. It is a a matter of personal preferences, but the outdated implicit joins can't be used to express an outer join. So it's better to always stick to the "modern" (introduced 30 years ago) explicit JOIN operators then you don't need to get used to different join styles

Comment: Implicit joins are not a way one can recommend. Optimizing a query by writing it in one line is just nonsense.

Comment: @DonKim As you can see, he has nothing to say against the multi-table selections that he single-sidedly declares them "ancient and outdated". These are not ancient and not outdated, he is just looking for conflicts. I still say that it is up to you, what you write.

Comment: @klin This is why JOINs are looking more natural for you. Because they look as if you would make procedural coding. The "mental switch" to create pretty SQL code, if you deeply understand the logic of the declarative paradigm: *you do not describe, what the program should do. Instead, you describe, what would be the result*. If you write queries, do not imagine a procedural thingy which really JOINs the tables. This is generally not what behind the bars will happen. Instead, imagine a relational algebra with filters.

Comment: The main drawback of your solution IMO is that the mixing of join and filter conditions in the `where` clause. For more complex queries it could to become unreadable.

Comment: @Abelisto This is absolutely not so. My [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705392/postgresql-can-this-query-could-be-shorter/66705460?noredirect=1#comment117917016_66705460) is also for you. It depends on, how do you think on the declarative code. If you think on it procedurally (i.e. as if something would really create the cartasian product of the tables), then yes, it will be hard to understand. But not this is what you should think on.

Comment: @Abelisto  You should think on as if it would be pure math: some "wizard" creates the cartasian product of all the tables, and then another "wizard" filters out, what you want from them.

Comment: I never said that selecting from multiple tables is ancient. I only said that doing an _implicit_ join in the WHERE clause is ancient. And it **is**. It was introduced with with SQL 86 and (which qualifies as "ancient" in IT) and was superseded with the explicit JOIN operators in SQL 89 three years later as "qualified joins" when outer joins where introduced.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Already the "implicit join" is a bad terminology - it enforces to thinking always, exclusively in JOINs even if they are not needed. This is why I do not use it. Btw, I have no problem of using JOINs, I have problem by making code more complex as needed. Beside that, also SQL is "ancient" - but somehow it works very well, maybe because data can be best described on a declarative and not on a procedural way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What does not work with solution, and somehow none of the commenter even tried to mention it: this solution can not be extended by a (left or outer) JOIN later easily. Then, really only the JOIN-way works.

Comment: It's impossible to write an outer join with the join style you prefer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, and also a left join. More clearly, it could be done with the UNION of multiple SELECTs, which would be longer and slower than JOINs. Fortunately this question is not so complex.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I said, it would be possible to emulate it with an UNION of multiple SELECTs, but it would be long and slow. If there is an OUTER or LEFT join, then the best is if they are there. However, if a query has only INNER JOINs, I see no reason to not simplify it to a multi-table SELECT.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did not want you to delete your answer, Abelisto's benchmark made it likely that it is faster. My problem was only that you have a problem with this simplification :-)